# UITableView design

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView where I want design as below.

[image]

For this I have images as below.

### bottomRow.png

[image]

### middleRow.png

[image]

### topAndBottomRow.png

[image]

### topRow.png

[image]

For this I have used below code inside `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

```
UIImage *selectedImage;
if (indexPath.row==0) {
    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];
} else if (indexPath.row == ([products count]-1)) {
    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
} else {
    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
}

if ([products count]==1) {
    selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
}

UIImageView *selectedBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedImage];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundImageView;

selectedBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedImage];
cell.backgroundView = selectedBackgroundImageView;
```

Now, everything works perfect.

**BUT** my designer is insisting on below point.

On tableview, I can have 4 cells at one time. Now let's say I have 6 rows.

Now when I have 6 rows (and tableview can show only 4), the 4th row shows `bottomRow.png` which is obvious. But my designer is insisting, even the tableview is scrolled, you should have same design for all 4 rows.

---

### Edit 1

First of all, sorry for not being clear.

Well when the UITableView loads, I can only see first 4 cells even there are 6 cells because I have set the height of tableview accordingly. To see rest 2 cells, I have to scroll down. I believe this is how table view works.

Now let's say there are only 4 records. For 4 records, table view looks like image I have.

Now when I have tableview size as 6 (with id as 1-6), the fourth row gets image middleRow.png. Here what my designer wanted is to see bottomRow.png.

Now let's say I scroll down. Now I see row with cell id as 3-6. Now cell with id 3 have middleRow.png, but my designer wanted to see topRow.png.

I know this is ugly, but this is what my designer wanted to see.

**Any suggestions to get this done?**

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your designer why you have 6 rows and TableView show only 4? would you please explain.

Comment: I don't know if I didn't understand but it seems like your code would work with any number of rows. The middleRow is used if the row is not the first nor the last.

Comment: @null : I have updated question. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @FelipeCypriano : yes, but that is not what I wanted. see my updated question

Comment: I think your designer is wrong and needs to be educated.

Comment: @NicholasHart : I know, but what he is saying is also correct. He just wanted to see design of tableview in format as I have in image **IRRESPECTIVE** of number of rows in uitableview.

Comment: And how should the top or bottom row be displayed if it is partially visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal: Use numberOfRows to find out if this cell is the last cell. 
In your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row==0) {
   selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];

.....

else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1){
   selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
}
```

---

EDIT:

Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I have another proposal that I think you may try...

1. customCell, with a custom method to set its image. For example,

   ```
   [customCell setSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
   ```

2.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can set all cells to be: middleRow.png

3.
After loading of tableView, run a checking method using [self.tableView visibleCells];

eg

```
 - (void) setImageForTopAndBottomCells{

         CustomCell *topCell = [[self.tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex: 0];
         CustomCell *bottomCell = [[self.tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex: self.tableView.visibleCells.count-1];

         [topCell setSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"]; 
         [bottomCell setSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"]; 
  }
```

1. If your tableView is scrollable, set your ViewController as a UIScrollView delegate, in your delegate method scrollViewDidScroll, run the setImageForTopAndBottomCells method again.

There could be better ways for achieving what you want than the one I proposed, let me know if you found one.

Comment: nope... not working... `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]` gives total number of rows in tableView...

Comment: what you are telling is also done by `else if (indexPath.row == ([products count]-1)) {`. `products count` gives total number of rows in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a combination of `scrollViewDidScroll:`, `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` with something like this:

1. Every time the table view scrolls you get the list of visible rows using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll:`
2. If it scrolled enough to change the background, call the `UITableView`'s `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing all the index paths that needs new background
3. Instead of using `indexPath.row == 0` to find the top you would use `[indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows][0]]` and the same thing for the other rows

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middlerow.png as background view of your UITableViewCell in **CellForRowAtIndexPath** method. Below is the code

```
 cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage[[UIImageimageNamed:@"middlerow.png"]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
```

And after this you can change the Corner radius (add border color/width) of your table view. But for this first you will have to add **QuartzCore** framework.

```
self.table.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:209.0/255 green:209.0/255 blue:209.0/255 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
self.table.layer.borderWidth =3.0;
self.table.layer.cornerRadius =10.0;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this:

```
NSArray *visible = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:0];
```

**-(NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows** returns an array of index paths each identifying a visible row in the receiver.So once you get the visible rows, you can use the required image according to indexpath.row.